# How do I generate a custom designed QR Code including app icon?

Tags: java, android, qr-code

1. Colorful QR Code
2. With App Icon in the center.
3. Almost like Snapchat.
4. For every new device a new Unique Qr Code
5. This QR Code cannot be scanned by anyother QR Scanner
6. and QR Code Scanner to scan only this QR Code

I have already searched online for this, but found nothing for android only got results for website based apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this
[Library](https://android-arsenal.com/details/3/4340).
All your conditions are can fulfilled but Point 5 and 6 are not possible as all QR codes use the same format.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks, do you know anyway that it cannot be scan able by other QR scanners like Snapchat QR